# System.Text.Json - Team Foundation Server Cant Find Namspace

Tags: c#, tfs

I am current having issues on the Continuous Integration process to Microsoft team foundation server. The namespace System.Text.Json cannot be found. As a result the build is failing on TFS

However it does work on my local visual studio:

Team foundation server Build:
[image: Team foundation server Build]

Visual Studio:
[image: Visual Studio]

Build Definition:
[image: Build Definition]

[[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlTnU.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKMze.png)

Comment: Please share the configuration of your build pipeline task, it seems you are using the old msbuild to build the project.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT, I am using the classic editor, please view

Comment: What is version of the Visual studio on your private agent server? Have you tried to update the visual studio version?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT, I am using visual studio 2019

Answer (score -1):

In summary, you will need to give your pipeline a bit of love and update to  build a new .NET (e.g. .NET6) codebase.

The output from the build agent suggest the build process for .NET framework.

You may to update a YAML pipeline and build you sln with something like:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build abc and tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: |
      .../.../abc.csproj
      .../.../abc.tests.csproj
    arguments: '--configuration Release'
```

You can stay with classic pipelines and use the .NET Core task:

[image]

---

Btw. your build agent uses an old version of Nuget (4.6). The current version is around 6.2.

Comment: I am using the classic editor, how can I solve this issue if the problem is only on TFS

Comment: Have you upgraded all you projects just some?

Comment: The framework is MVC 4 and I used System.Text.Json Nuget package 4.6.0

Comment: You need to "Edit build definition" (or clone the current pipeline and edit the new pipeline for safety)

Comment: Please view the Build definition on the edited question